# countable set of open sets in a compact uniform space

Tags: general-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal{U})$ be  a compact uniform space which is not metrizable and and $\{U_i\}_{i=0}^{\infty}$ be a countable set of $U_i\in \mathcal{U}$ with $U_{i-1}\subseteq U_i$ and $U_1\subseteq V$. It can to see that there is open set $W\in \mathcal{U}$ such that $U_i\cap W^{c}\neq \emptyset$ (See [a compact uniform space which is not metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2361282/a-compact-uniform-space-which-is-not-metrizable?rq=1)).

Q. What can say about non-emptyset $U_i\cap W^{c}$, Is it an infinite set?

Comment: What is $V$? Besides, your link does not work.

Comment: The proof in the paper you're reading (see other question) doesn't require an infinite set, just one point for every $i$, so we do construct some infinite set. The $U_i$ are not open per se, they are entourages, which often aren't open.

Comment: Dear Prof. Henno Brandsma, Thanks a lot for your reply, It is interesting for me to see that if $(X, \mathcal{U})$ is a compact uniform space and it is not metrizable and let $f$ be a homeomorphism of $X$ on to $X$. For $U\in \mathcal{U}$, Do there exist infinite set $A\subseteq X$  such that $(f^{n}(x), f^{n}(y))\in U$ for all $x,y\in A$ and all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Theorem 1 in the paper only proves they're at least 2 distinct $x$ and $y$ like that. If we had infinitely many, what would happen to a limit point of $A$? Maybe cut out open neighbourhoods of the first pair $x,y$ like that and repeat the argument on a smaller, hopefully still non-metrisable, compact space?

Comment: Let $\Gamma_D(x)=\{y:(f^{n}(y), f^{n}(x))\in D, for all n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. $f$ is called expansive whenever $\Gamma_D(x)=\{x\}$ for all $x\in X$.  If there is an expansive homeomorphism on compact uniform space $(X,\mathcal{U})$, then $X$ is metrizable (Theorem 1). We say that $f$ is finite expansive if there is entourage $D$ such that $\Gamma_D(x)$ is finite for all $x\in X$. It is interesting for me to know that  If there is  a finite expansive homeomorphism on compact uniform space $(X, \mathcal{U})$.  Is  it  true that  $X$ is a metric space?